# Künneth formula for cohomology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

I see that most authors prove only the Künneth formula for Homology, and get the formula for cohomology as a consequence. My question here is how to get from one to the other. I assume you need to use the Universal Coefficient Theorem. So My approach is the following.

For all that follows assume $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, $R$ is a PID and $M$ is an $R$-module.

The two things I understand is that in this conditions we have the following short exact split squences

**The Universal Coefficient Theorem for Cohomology**
$$0\rightarrow  \text{Ext}_R(H_{n-1}(X;R),M) \rightarrow H^n(X;M) \rightarrow \text{Hom}_R(H_n(X;R),M) \rightarrow 0$$

**The Künneth formula for Homology**
$$0 \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=0}^n H_i(X;R)\otimes H_{n-i}(Y;R) \rightarrow H_n(X\times Y) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=0}^{n-1} \text{Tor}(H_i(X;R), H_{n-1-i}(Y;R)) \rightarrow 0$$

From what I have seen the cohomology version is pretty much the same exact sequence, just replacing $H_k$ with $H^k$ everywhere in the sequence above.

My question is, how do you use what I have mentioned to arrive at the cohomology version of the Künneth formula?

Comment: You may find [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/107742/21564) and its answers relevant.

Comment: I remember that there is a convention to write the complex $\operatorname{Hom}(C_p;\Bbb{Z})$ as $C'_{-p}$ (assign it dimension $-p$ because there is a contravariant functor applied on the chain group). Then, the Künneth formula for homology applies. Then, use $H_{-p}(C'\otimes D')\cong H^p(C\otimes D)$ to get things back, and you get the Künneth formula for cohomology....Correct me if I am wrong.